# How do I know if I set up the network load balancing cluster correctly?

Tags: windows-server-2008, cluster, nlb

I'm working on a web conference where we are going to show about 12 videos for a total of about half a gig. Since all the participants are going to be watching (and also streaming/downloading) at once, it was recommended we set up a server farm. So i have 4 servers that i am trying to network together. They are all running Microsoft Server 2008 and I have spent the last three days setting them up and now that its done I want to make sure it's all ready to go. So I just want to be sure that everything is setup the way that I think it is. What is the best way to do this? Really I want to make sure that the load will be split over the servers when it's showtime.

Comment: Dave, was any of this helpful? Did you ever get your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Go to one or all (preferably all) of your NLB cluster nodes and type `wlbs query` and/or `wlbs display` and inspect the output. Also, ping the shared IP locally and then remotely. If you've got a reply, then your cluster is good to go. If you want to go a bit deeper, I suppose you could create multiple connections to the cluster by accessing a file that the cluster is serving up and monitor each node with Wireshark or even simply watch each network interface's statistics using Performance Monitor.

Comment: i guess im still a little confused, the remote ping of the shared IP didn't work. I guess i don't understand how the "public" is to be able to get to the shared IP (Virtual IP). how do i get a shared IP that the "public" can access

Comment: What you need to do is to "map" or NAT the public ip address to the VIP of the cluster in your router or firewall. So for instance, if the public ip that you plan to use is 1.1.1.1 and the VIP is 10.10.10.10, then in your firewall or router set up a NAT entry to NAT (map) 1.1.1.1 to 10.10.10.10.

Comment: thank you soo much for the response. does anyone know a good resource to read up about that?

Comment: What kind of firewall\router do you have?

Comment: im not sure about the router but im using microsoft server 2008 so windows firewall

Comment: You'll need to edit your router (whatever device has the public IP address that you'll be pointing people to) to pass traffic to the internet cluster IP address. Since it's web based traffic, I'll assume that you'll be forwarding only port 80 to the cluster IP. When you mentioned "im using microsoft server 2008 so windows firewall", I think you're referencing your cluster servers which don't really come into play here as far as NATing is concerned. Just make sure that they're not blocking port 80 traffic, which they shouldn't be is you set up IIS/Apache/Whatever correctly.